# Chevy sonic 2014

Tags: engine, chevrolet, sonic

I have a Chevy sonic 2014, purchased from B M W about 2 months ago. My car smelled like it was getting warm. Opened the hood brown sludge. Mechanic says it isn't a head gasket and are unable to detect what is wrong. Any light you can shed would be appreciated.

Comment: where did you see the brown sludge? In the oil? In the radiator?

Comment: Some pictures would help here

Comment: Where did you see the brown sludge?